# Python simple contact manager application. Delete contact function issues

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am working on an assignment for school, and am having some trouble with one of the functions.

The assignment is a simple contact manager application and I am having trouble with the delete contact function. The instructions say to first display a numbered list of contacts from a txt file and ask the user which number they want to delete. I should then iterate through the file using a for loop and a counter. The program should add each line to the empty  string when the counter does NOT equal the user input. It should then write the new list to the txt file.

The problem I am having is that when I enter a number it deletes that number and everything below it. It is like the loop stops when it matches the counter to user input. Here is the code I have so far for the delete contact function:

```
def del_contact(contacts):

    view_contacts(contacts)

    choose_contact = int(input("Please enter the number of the contact you wish to delete: "))

    contacts_file = open(contacts, 'r')

    new_list = ""
    line_count = 1

    for line in contacts_file:

        if line_count != choose_contact:

            new_list += line
            line_count += 1

    contacts_file.close()

    print(new_list)

    #contacts_new = open(contacts, 'w')

    #contacts_new.write(new_list)

    #print("Contact deleted.")
    print()
```

I am brand new to this so I am sure it is something simple I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `line_count == choose_contact` you don't increment `line_count` by `1`:

```
if line_count != choose_contact:
    new_list += line
    line_count += 1
```

Next time the `for` loop runs the `line_count` value will still be the same and will still be equal to `choose_contact`. You should increment `line_count` no matter what (note the indentation):

```
if line_count != choose_contact:
    new_list += line
line_count += 1
```

That being said, it is better to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of keeping your own counter in such loops.